# Set editor widget type for a given layer/field with PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, fields-attributes, widget

I would like to set the editor widget type for a a given field of a layer with PyQGIS. The actual widget type can be retrieved for example like

```
>>> iface.activeLayer().editFormConfig().widgetType('text_x')
u'TextEdit'
```

**How can I set this to editor widget type `Hidden`, for example?**

I tried:

```
>>> iface.activeLayer().editFormConfig().setWidgetType('text_x', u'Hidden')
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: QgsEditFormConfig.setWidgetType(int, QString): argument 1 has unexpected type 'str'
```

And also:

```
from qgis.gui import *
iface.activeLayer().editFormConfig().setWidgetType('text_x', QgsHiddenWidgetWrapper)
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'QgsHiddenWidgetWrapper' is not defined
```

From the doku https://qgis.org/api/2.18/classQgsEditFormConfig.html#afc55a3ae3b331225dd69b561d0d437bd the correct 'spelling' of setting up the widget type is not so clear to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just found an answer on my own (monday mornings...). I just did not see that `setWidgetType()` wants the field ID as input, not the field name, so I have to

```
>>> iface.activeLayer().fields().indexFromName('text_x')
7
iface.activeLayer().editFormConfig().setWidgetType(7, u'Hidden')
```

or using `setEditorWidgetV2()` directly on the layer:

```
iface.activeLayer().setEditorWidgetV2(7, u'Hidden')
```